# how to click the login button using selenium xpath

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler

I am trying to login to a website using python so that I can get some of their text from the website.

Here is my code. There always an error at the end of the code after the id and password code.

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get('https://www.saramin.co.kr/zf_user/auth')

driver.implicitly_wait(3)

driver.find_element_by_name('id').send_keys('<<my_id>>')
driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys('<<my_password>>')

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="frmNIDLogin"]/fieldset/input').click()
```

HTML source of the button:

[image]

Comment: The html doesn't match the `xpath` in your code. And post the html as text please, not as an image.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I figured it out! Thanks for your answer though.

Here is the final code.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")

browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('https://www.saramin.co.kr/zf_user/auth')

driver.implicitly_wait(3)

driver.find_element_by_name('id').send_keys('ID') driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys('PW')

driver.find_element_by_xpath( '//*[@class="btn-login"]' ).click()
```

Comment: It worth noticing `'//*[@class="btn-login"]'` match two elements. It works because the relevant element is first in the DOM hierarchy,  it might not always be that way.

Answer (score 0):

The `xpath` is incorrect, it doesn't match anything in the page. Try

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//form[@id="login_frm"]//button[@class="btn-login"]').click()
```

or simply use `submit()` function on the `<form>`

```
form = driver.find_element_by_id('login_frm')
form.submit()
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first case you were using `'id' ('//*[@id="frmNIDLogin"])`  for click button, because `'id'` changes every time page loads it was giving error. But in the second case when you used `class ( '//*[@class="btn-login"]' )` it worked because it remains same every time page is loaded. Also as mentioned above the value of id in first case was wrong.